# Smooth background transition and zoom animation in one does not fit the container

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transition

Basing on some examples I have found here on SO I tried to mash up two effects: smooth background change within the slow zooming in animation. The thing is once the zooming animation starts from the scale of `1.0 to 1.{whatever}` it grows outside the div's boundary whereas I want to keep fixed div's dimensions. Please note that `background-size:cover;` is laced in the code and it works fine only for the initial scale.

You can find example I am struggling with here : http://mattosuch.eu/test.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an outer `div` to each `div` elements that scaling and give CSS to newly created `div` like this.

```
div.outer{
height: 200px; /*Equal to real height of your inner div with `transform:scale(1,1)`*/
width: 200px; /*Equal to real width of your inner div with `transform:scale(1,1)`*/
overflow: hidden;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use only CSS, animation and pseudo-elements to fake background-animation about the fading effect :

Here is an example with 3 image used as backgrounds fading and zooming after each others.

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://seraphe.nazwa.pl/docs/photojoy/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Lucy6-scaled.jpg) center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: scale 12s infinite;
  position: relative;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  background: url(http://seraphe.nazwa.pl/docs/photojoy/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Zosia-8-scaled.jpg) center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: scale 12s -6s infinite, hide 12s -6s infinite;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}

div:after {
  background: url(http://seraphe.nazwa.pl/docs/photojoy/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Nadia1-scaled.jpg)center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  animation: scale 12s 6s infinite, hide 12s 6s infinite;
}

@keyframes scale {
  80% {
    background-size: auto 200%;
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  from,
  to {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- empty div to show fading backgrounds. Without CSS or a screen reader it is empty -->
</div>
```

1 element (+ 2pseudos elements)  gives the opportunity to load 3 .

You can animate fading via opacity and scaling via background-size through animations.

You can reset the length of your animation and also the values and numbers of steps to animate .
You can also use background-position and switch multiple background-image position while opacity is set to 0.  example using 4 for image, one pseudo uses multiple bg-image wich are switching position while unseen. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zzbXem

Comment: Okay, thanks to you and colleague above I have managed to fix the issue.
But now, it scales also the child elements, whereas I want to scale the parent's background only. Any advice?

Comment: @MateuszOsuch if you use scale, then use also scale for the direct child to scale it back down while parent scales up. the bg approach would avoid this even that overflow is a quick n easy fix ;)

Comment: @MateuszOsuch  example with child, pseudos and bg resized. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zzbXem